# how can i update related tables in one query with mysql

Tags: mysql, database

i have 3 tables **items**, **sales** and **orders** in mysql
items has an id `item_id` and `stock` columns
while **sales** and **orders** have an `item_id` column
i want to insert into **sales/orders** and use the inserted `item_id` in the **sales/orders** column to update the `stock` column in **items** by adding or subtracting a number

i know i can do it individually but i want to know if it's possible to do it in one query or in a way less prone to error I'm worried one query can pass and the other fail

```sql
INSERT INTO sale(id, item_id, amount ) VALUES  ('random_id1', 'item_id1', '10');
UPDATE items SET stock = previous_stock - 10 WHERE item_id = item_id1
```

is it even a good idea to combine it or is separate better ?

Comment: You can update multiple tables with a join, but there's no way to combine update and insert of different tables.

Comment: Use a transaction so you get both changes or neither.